# LESS mixin with loop creating background images

Tags: css, loops, less

I need to create many background-images for boxes and i'd like to use mixins. I want to call it with 2 parameters: number and name.

I've tried that:

```
.counter(@counter; @name) { // outer mixin
  .counter(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
    .counter((@counter - 1));    // next iteration
    .cat-wrapper-@{name} .cat-@{counter} {
       background-image: url('/mediafiles/@{name}/cat_@{counter}.jpg')
    }
  }
}

.counter(2;'name');
```

In the end I want it to output:

```
.cat-wrapper-name .cat-1 {
    background-image: url('mediafiles/name/cat_1.jpg');
}
.cat-wrapper-name .cat-2 {
    background-image: url('mediafiles/name/cat_2.jpg');
}
```

It compiles without errors but doesn't output any code. 
When I delete `@name` and just use 1 parameter `@counter` it works. But with 2 parameters it doesn't.

Comment: `.counter(2;'name');` is this a typo? `.counter(2, name);`

Comment: Should work with `.counter(2, name);`

Comment: @Huangism that was not the problem. when i remove the outer wrapper it compiles even when i just put 1 parameter in the outer wrapper.

Comment: I think it is because your counter mixin takes in 2 required parameters and in the inner counter mixin calls, you are only passing 1 parameter

Comment: @Huangism than it outputs: cat-wrapper-name, but i want the name dynamically. 
.counter(30, cars)
.counter(15, bikes)
etc.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the issue is you are over complicating things and missing second parameter. Your code above calls to counter which is NOT a recursive mixin, the inner recursive mixin does not get invoked at any time which is why you never see any generated code. It isn't like lot of other programming languages where it would run the code inside of the function

```
.counter(@counter, @name) when (@counter > 0) {
    .counter((@counter - 1), @name);    // next iteration
    .cat-wrapper-@{name} .cat-@{counter} {
       background-image: url('/mediafiles/@{name}/cat_@{counter}.jpg')
    }
}

.counter(2, name);
```

Recursive mixin `.counter(@counter, @name: name) when (@counter > 0)`

You need that second parameter and it needs to be optional, since you are not calling it `.counter((@counter - 1));`

OR

you pass it to the count-1 call which I have done in my above code `.counter(@counter, @name)` and then again at `.counter((@counter - 1), @name);`

You don't need the outer mixin, it serves no purpose

You can test this here https://lesstester.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now, but i needed to remove the ', like .counter(2;name);

Comment: Yea you don't need quotes for strings